# Define a partial derivative of a composite function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction

I would like to define the function $ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\dfrac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}\right)$, for example

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + 3 y^3;
g[x_, y_] := x + 2 y;
g0[x_, y_] := f[x, y]/g[x, y];
h[x_, y_] := Derivative[0, 1][g0][x, y]
```

how is it possible to do it without using the intermediate function g0?
the code

```
Derivative[0, 1][f/g][x, y]
```

is not working.

PS. Of course, one can differentiate by parts, but it is not the easiest solution

Comment: Do you mean D[f[x, y]/g[x, y], y]?

Comment: hh[x_, y_] := D[f[x, y]/g[x, y], y];
hh[1,0] returns an error

Comment: That's because you are trying to differentiate with respect to the numbers 1 and 0 in this case... Try `hh[xVal_, yVal_] := D[f[x, y]/g[x, y], y] /. {x -> xVal, y -> yVal}`. Then it works with `hh[1,0]` as well as `hh[x,y]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a pure (anonymous) function in the middle

```
h[x_, y_] := Derivative[0, 1][f[#, #2]/g[#, #2] &][x, y]
```

as its name suggests, attaching a name to it is not a necessity.

Some testable results are

```
h[x, y] // FullSimplify
h[1, 0]
```

> ```
> (-2 x^2 + 9 x y^2 + 12 y^3)/(x + 2 y)^2
> -2
> ```

Comment: thx. what does mean '&' in your code?

Comment: @Chipa-Chipa `&` is a delimiter before (left to) which lies the scope of the pure function.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to evaluate [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D) before giving it numbers (i.e, use [`Set (=)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set) instead of [`SetDelayed (:=)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed) in the definition of h):

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + 3 y^3;
g[x_, y_] := x + 2 y;
h[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y]/g[x, y], y];
```

Then:

```
h[x, y]
h[1, 0]
```

> (9 y^2)/(x + 2 y) - (2 (x^2 + 3 y^3))/(x + 2 y)^2
>
> -2